# soap connection through jquery in phonegap?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova

is it possible to do cross domain through j query in phone gap? I know cross domain will be supported in phone gap. can we do SOAP,REST web services through phone gap using j query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use web services calls in phonegap. When I developed for iphone using phonegap we used a ton of web service calls to update and push and pull data to our servers.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or post methods would work.

Just look for examples on the web to jquery ajax calls i just used json to push and pull data but implementing a soap call shouldn't be that much harder.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, if you upgrade your Webservices to handle JSONP calls instead of JSON/SOAP. With the help of JQuery.Ajax, you can call these services remotely.

If you're using .Net Webservices, here's a fine example:

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx